# $|y'(x)|$ versus $d|y|/dx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, inequality

$$|y'(x)|$$ versus $$\frac{d|y|}{dx}$$ which one is bigger?

---

**Attempt**

Assuming $|y|$ and $y$ is differentiable everywhere. The derivative of $\frac{d|y|}{dx}$ at a point $x$ is either $y'(x)$ or $-y'(x)$. While $|y'(x)|$ is definitely the maximum of those two: $max(y'(x), -y'(x))$. So we can say

$$ \frac{d|y|}{dx} \le |y'(x)| $$

Answer (score 0):

One can simply use the (reverse) triangle inequality:
If both $y$ and $w = |y|$ are differentiable at a point $x$ then
$$
 | |y(x+h)| - |y(x)| | \le |y(x+h) - y(x)|
$$
implies that
$$
  |w'(x)| \le |y'(x)| \,
$$
this holds even for vector-valued functions where one cannot argue with the sign of $y'$.

For real-valued functions $y$ it follows that in particular $ w'(x) \le |w'(x)| \le |y'(x)|$.